# Repercussions of opening ports for applications on router

Tags: networking, router, firewall, home-networking, port-forwarding

I know there's a security risk with forwarding ports on my router to a computer on my network for applications like teamspeak or minecraft.  However, I haven't seen any clear explanations of what the repercussions can be.

What can a hacker potentially do with an open port on my router pointing to a single PC?  There are a boat load of other systems and devices on the network with little to no layers of extra security.

And also, is there a way to securely setup the forward to minimize the risks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a TCP port to a host behind a NAT or firewall allows unsolicited connection attempts to be made to that host from the Internet.  These connection attempts then have to be handled by the operating system of that host, which either pass on the connection to an application that is bound to that port, or, if none, reject the connection attempt.

Should that particular application or operating system version have a security hole that allows a remote entity to take control of that system by way of that open port, arbitrary software could then be installed on that system to perform malicious activities on the network with all the implicit trust given to the private system, including sending email, accessing databases and fileservers, viewing and posting to internal web pages (such as the router configuration web page), as well as logging local network traffic, and viewing unencrypted network data.

While this post could not attempt to cover the exhaustive breadth and depth of potential security risks punching a hole in a firewall/NAT can have, each individual system that can be reached from the public Internet increases by a large exponential degree, the chances of the network being compromised.

Here, perhaps more so than other analogies, the security of the network is only as strong as its weakest link.  A general purpose computing system running consumer software is a very weak link, even compared to the lowliest NAT router.

Comment: Thank you Nevin, puts it into good perspective again.  I already accepted Devan's answer, but yours was informative as well.   This definitely makes me rethink hosting these services in house altogether though.   Been doing it for years off and on but this out does seem too risky overall without some sort connection whitelist.

Comment: Well, there's the concept of the DMZ (Demilitarized Zone) which is usually a small network between the ISP's router, and the customer's firewall;  Devices on the DMZ are usually untrusted, and have no implicit access to corporate systems or databases.   The DMZ is where devices that need full access to the Internet are placed, and are inherently distrusted --  presumed hacked --, and treated accordingly.

Comment: That might actually be an interesting approach for me as well.  I could potentially run a virtual machine in the dmz with no expectation of security on it.   though I won't neglect security entirely and at least place a software firewall/av on it.   But mostly it's just a kamikaze workstation.  I like the simplicity behind that solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that an attacker can use this open port to gain access to your single computer. (Various ways all depending on the attack method). If they gain access to the single computer they then can attack the rest of the network with a broader attack. This is because the information between devices behind the firewall are usually not checked by consumer routers. **This is why it is very important to have firewall and antivirus on ALL devices within the network.**

A short list of possible things that an attacker can do while on your network :
Reroute network traffic to a server they control
Control your computer as if they were sitting at it
Steal information (such as banking information)

I am learning to run a server at home and have only 3 ports forwarded. While this has been only up for a short time, my bandwidth is impacted because I have logs full of different IPs trying to gain access.

To help mitigate this risk you can edit the rules of the port forward to only accept the connections from the IP of the people connectiong to you. Theoretically you should not need to create port forward rulles if you are connecting out, only if you have people connecting to a service you are hosting. Consumer routers generally don't block outgoing connections.

There are many guides to help with securing your network. I would google `"Securely run a server from home"` to get some ideas.

Comment: Thank you Devon. I figured it was that bad. I just never saw it in plain writing.  I hadn't thought about setting up incoming rules before though.  My user list is pretty small so that might be an option for me.  I'll have to check what my ddwrt can do for that.

Comment: @Residualfail My limited understanding of DDWRT is that it is pretty robust and should be able to accommodate your needs :)